# irreducible representations of $GL_2$ over $p$-adic field

Tags: representation-theory

Let $E$ be a finite extension of $\mathbf{Q}_p$. In class we stated the following fact :

Every irreducible algebraic representation of $GL_2(E)$ is of the form 
$$
\mathrm{Sym}^{k-2}(E^2) \otimes_E {\det}^m
$$
for $k \geq 2$ and $m \in \mathbf{Z}$

Questions : 
1) What does algebraic mean here ?
2) do you know a reference ?

Comment: I would guess algebraic means that it needs to be a representation of this as an algebraic group (these are also called rational representations). As for a reference, it follows from the general results in Jantzen's book on algebraic groups, though that may well be overkill (and the exposition there is aimed at working in positive characteristic with an algebraically closed field, so there are almost certainly better sources more concerned with the $p$-adic case).

Comment: A word of warning: That book has some pretty heavy prerequisites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To confirm what Tobias said, "algebraic" in this case means a homomorphism of algebraic groups $GL_2(E)\rightarrow GL_N(E)$ for some $N$, i.e. a group homomorphism defined via polynomial functions. A slight word of warning: in the earlier years of the subject, an "algebraic representation" of a $p$-adic group such as $GL_2(E)$ meant something *very* different to this (what's now usually called a smooth representation).

As for the most straightforward proof that I can think of, let me sketch out how you can do this by first considering $SL_2(E)$. Let me cover myself by saying that I haven't thought very carefully about the details, but I don't think that anything should go wrong; maybe some things will just be a bit harder than I'm claiming.

A fairly well-known result is the classification of the finite-dimensional irreducible complex representations of the Lie algebra $\frak{sl}_2(\Bbb{C})$, which is via looking at highest weights. This leads to the result that the irreducible representations are precisely the representations $Sym^{k-2}(\Bbb{C}^2)$. In fact, this holds more generally: one obtains the same classification of the $k$-representations of ${\frak{sl}}_2(k)$ for any field $k$ of characteristic $0$: see [here, for example](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/210CPage/handouts/sl2rep.pdf).

The algebraic group $SL_2(E)$ has a Lie algebra defined in a way reasonably analogous to the usual definition (the tangent space at the identity identifies with derivations and inherits a Lie bracket), which leads to the usual result that it's Lie algebra is ${\frak{sl}}_2(E)$ as above, namely the Lie algebra of 2x2 traceless matrices over $E$. Then by the usual argument of "differentiating" an irreducible algebraic representation of $SL_2(E)$, one obtains an irreducible representation of ${\frak{sl}}_2(E)$. So one needs only to classify the irreducible representations of ${\frak{sl}}_2(E)$, and then note that every such representation arises via "differentiation", in order to classify the irreducible algebraic representations of $SL_2(E)$.

It then remains to extend this classification to $GL_2(E)$ (in a general setting, this is fairly common: $GL_2$ is a reductive group with derived subgroup $SL_2$. The group $SL_2$ is semisimple, and so a bit easier to work with as one doesn't really have to worry about the centre, and the representation theories of the two groups are closely related). Let me write $V(k)$ for the representation $Sym^{k-2}(E^2)$ of $SL_2(E)$. Since the action of $SL_2(E)$ on $E^2$ clearly extends to an action of $GL_2(E)$ (which obviously remains algebraic), $V(k)$ extends to a representation of $GL_2(E)$ for any $k\geq 2$. This means that any irreducible representation of $GL_2(E)$ which contains $V(k)$ upon restriction to $SL_2(E)$ must be isomorphic to $V(k)\otimes\chi$, where $\chi$ is some irreducible representation of $GL_2(E)/SL_2(E)\simeq G_m(E)$, viewed as a representation of $GL_2(E)$ via inflation. It's easy to see that the only such $\chi$ are the powers of $\det$: use the classification of characters of $G_m(E)$ (it's a split torus of rank 1 so they are precisely the characters $x\mapsto x^m$ for $m\in\Bbb{Z}$) and then note that inflating to $GL_2(E)$ means pulling back through $\det$, so $\chi$ is of the form $x\mapsto\det(x^m)$, i.e. $\chi=\det^m$.

Comment: That is an absolutely fantastic answer. Thank you so very much !! (P.S. I can't upvote because i'm not a registered user)

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: It is interesting to note that characteristic $0$ is also used in the step from the group to the Lie algebra (or rather, for the step back again), since this step fails in positive characteristic, where the Lie algebra can only "detect" the representations of the first Frobenius kernel (the fix is to consider the algebra of distributions instead, which coincides with the enveloping algebra of the Lie algebra in characteristic $0$).